# Why can't I call the functions within the class?

Tags: python, oop

I just started Python OOP. I have to build a simple class and function, but I don't understand why it works in one case, but doesn't in the other.

```py
class Digital_signal_information:
    def __init__(self, signal_power: float, noise_power: float, n_bit_mod: int):
        self.signal_power = signal_power
        self.noise_power = noise_power
        self.n_bit_mod = n_bit_mod

class Line:
    def __init__(self,loss_coefficient: float, length: int):
        self.loss_coefficient = loss_coefficient
        self.length = length
    
    def Loss(self, loss):
        self.loss = loss_coefficient * length

    BPSK = Digital_signal_information(0.001, 0, 1)           
    QPSK = Digital_signal_information(0.001, 0, 2) # In these 4 cases it works fine.                           
    Eight_QAM = Digital_signal_information(0.001, 0, 3)    
    Sixteen_QAM = Digital_signal_information(0.001, 0, 4) 
    

# But if I do
a = Line(1.0, 2);
# and try to call a.Loss, nothing is shown.
```

In the exercise I have to create the `Line` class on which I have to use the `signal_power` and `length` attributes. I also have to use a function (or property) (correct me if I'm wrong, I'm still getting used to the OOP vocabulary). But as said, I don't understand why it works in one part, but doesn't in the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@property` so that the return value of the function can be directly accessed as `a.Loss`.

```py
@property
def Loss(self):
    return self.loss_coefficient * self.length

# ...
a = Line(1.0,2)
print(a.Loss) # 2.0
```

Comment: Bloody hell i just figured out it was the spacing problem.

Comment: @SeverjanLici Can't reproduce. It works fine here: https://ideone.com/igMExV

Comment: Yes. I figured out what the problem was. Thank you

Comment: One more silly question. If i have to store that ```loss``` do i do this? ```self.loss = self.loss_coefficient * self.length``` ?

Comment: @SeverjanLici Yes, you can store it like that,

Answer (score 0):

[Unmitigated](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9513184/unmitigated) has already found out to use `property`. However, if your loss value is not designed to change over time (in other words, the `Line` object is designed to be [immutable](https://www.mygreatlearning.com/blog/understanding-mutable-and-immutable-in-python/)), you can also use [`functools.cached_property`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-functools-cached_property/). This behaves in the same way as `property`, but with one difference: it saves the first calculated value and all following times returns the saved one instead of calculating a new one.

The code remains almost the same as [Unmitigated](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9513184/unmitigated)'s code:

```py
from functools import cached_property

class Digital_signal_information:
    def __init__(self, signal_power: float, noise_power: float, n_bit_mod: int):
        self.signal_power = signal_power
        self.noise_power = noise_power
        self.n_bit_mod = n_bit_mod

class Line:
    def __init__(self, loss_coefficient: float, length: int):
        self.loss_coefficient = loss_coefficient
        self.length = length
    @cached_property
    def Loss(self):
        return self.loss_coefficient * self.length

    BPSK=Digital_signal_information(0.001, 0, 1)           
    QPSK = Digital_signal_information(0.001, 0, 2)       #basically in these 4 cases I have no problem                            
    Eight_QAM = Digital_signal_information(0.001, 0, 3)    
    Sixteen_QAM = Digital_signal_information(0.001, 0, 4) 
    

#but if I do
a = Line(1.0, 2)

print(a.Loss)
#and when I try to see if I can call a.Loss it shows nothing
```

You should **not** use this when the `Line` object is intended to change over time. For example, the following code has an incorrect output:

```py
print(a.Loss) # correct
a.length = 3
print(a.Loss) # not correct
```

Still some final remarks on your code:

- It is better to add spaces around operators and after commas. This makes your code more readable and allows you to change your code easier later on.
- In contrast to many other programming languages, python doesn't require semicolons (`;`) to seperate lines. It is thus useless to add one.